# How to assign the input of a method to the output of that very same method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to repeat a method of changing a string, so that the input of the method is the output of the same method that has been run. This will then be looped.

Here is the code excerpt:

```
public void start() {
    String inputString = "                                          ";
    boolean gameOver = false;

    while (!gameOver) {
        int column = columnResult();

        String tokens = enterToken("X", inputString,column);   
        System.out.println(tokens);

        enterToken("X", tokens, column);
        System.out.println(tokens);
    }
}

private int columnResult() {
    System.out.println("Enter column for X:");
    String keyInput = Keyboard.readInput();
    int column1 = Integer.parseInt(keyInput);
    return column1;
}

private String enterToken(String tokenSymbol, String inputString, int column){
    String columnEdit = inputString.substring(column*6-6,column*6); 

    String columnEdit1 = columnEdit.trim();
    String columnEdit2 = columnEdit1+tokenSymbol+"                 ";
    String columnEdit3 = columnEdit2.substring(0,6);
    String start = inputString.substring(0,column*6-6);
    String end = inputString.substring(column*6);

    System.out.println(start);
    return start+tokenSymbol+end;
}
```

So I'm trying to give the NEXT enterToken method the value returned from the PREVIOUS one. How might I achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you doing that already?

Comment: Whenever I enter a value during the loop, it just enters an X into the initial inputString, rather than taking the new one produced by the last enterToken.

Comment: You should improve your code sample. It not indented right, and contains unnecessary detail. (E.g. the specific string manipulation operations and user input.)

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem...

Your String variable only has scope within the loop, so when the loop iterates, it's a new variable. Define your String variable *outside* the loop, so its scope persists across loop iterations:

```
String tokens = inputString; // initialize the input
while (!gameOver) {
    int column = columnResult();
    // the result will be feed back in next iteration
    tokens = enterToken("X", tokens, column);   
    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```